# Find substring in a formatted phone number

Tags: objective-c

I have a `NSString` containing a formatted phone number such as `(123) 456-7890`. I want to find substring that match user's unformatted input.

So if input is `234` then the matching substring is `NSRange(2,5)` (which is `23) 4`). How do I go about implementing such as find method?

Thanks!

Comment: Filter out original phone number, remove all symbols except numbers. Do the same for user input, match both strings against => profit.

Comment: I need to find match in the formatted phone number so that I can know the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your user input and insert `[( )-]*` between each digit, then use a regular expression to find the matches, if any.

```
NSString *phoneNumber = @"(123) 456-7890";

NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                              regularExpressionWithPattern:@"2[( )-]*3[( )-]*4"
                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                              error:&error];
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:phoneNumber options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [phoneNumber length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){
    // your code to handle matches here
    NSLog(@"match at location: %lu  length: %lu", (unsigned long)match.range.location, (unsigned long)match.range.length);
}];
```

Comment: Awesome! Works great, thanks a ton! Clever use of regex.

Comment: The simpler NSString method can be used: `NSRange substringRange = [phoneNumber rangeOfString:@"2[( )-]*3[( )-]*4" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];`